# Shortcut for moving to previous input sequence?

Tags: ipython

Is there a shortcut for moving backwards in history, but not line by line?

I.e. not ctrl-p.

I want to skip from `In [3]:` to `In[2]:`, regardless of  how many lines `In [3]`: was

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this page](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts) to look into how to change the terminal IPython shortcut, or adding new ones. Maybe code for Ctrl-R to search backward may help with this, though it might be in prompt_toolkit source code.

You can also the [load magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=load%20magic#magic-load) that takes many things as input (including In prompt numbers) and load it in the prompt for editing. So `load 2<enter>` in your case?